# calculate multiple total sales of months

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

My desired output is shown below.I have tried to achieve it like this 
 *new_card_total = total sales

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp) as MonthName, 
       COUNT(*) as new_card_qty,
       ISNULL(sum(cl.nc_deposit),0) as new_card_total
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl  
       INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m 
       on cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id  
       INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl 
       on m.sales_id = sl.sales_id 
       INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h 
       on cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id  
       INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t 
       on h.terminal_id = t.terminal_id  
       INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c 
       on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id  
       INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_card_role cr 
       on cr.id = c.card_role_id 
       INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_top_up_logs tl 
       on tl.tu_log_id = m.tu_log_id 
WHERE YEAR(cl.nc_timestamp)= 2017   
and cl.currency_id = 1
and (cr_log_id is null or cr_log_id = 0)
and top_up_status = 1
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,cl.nc_timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp)

union all

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp) as MonthName, 
       COUNT(*) as new_card_qty, 
       ISNULL(sum(cl.nc_deposit),0) as new_card_total
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl  
     INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_map m 
     on cl.nc_log_id = m.nc_log_id  
     INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_sales_logs sl 
     on m.sales_id = sl.sales_id 
     INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal_user_account h 
     on cl.created_user_id = h.terminal_user_id  
     INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_terminal t 
     on h.terminal_id = t.terminal_id  
     INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_cuid c 
     on cl.cu_id = c.cu_id  
     INNER JOIN dbfastsconfigdataref.dbo.cdf_card_role cr 
     on cr.id = c.card_role_id 
     INNER JOIN dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_trans tr 
     on tr.trans_id = m.trans_id 
WHERE YEAR(cl.nc_timestamp)= 2017   
and cl.currency_id = 1
and (cr_log_id is null or cr_log_id = 0)
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,cl.nc_timestamp), DATEPART(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp)
```

with output :

```
 monthname        new_card_qty          new_card_value
 -----------------------------------------------------------
  jan                 100                   1000
  feb                 200                   2000
  march               300                   3000
  march               400                   5000
  april               500                   6000
  april               500                   8000
```

and i would like to have output like this:

```
 monthname        new_card_qty          new_card_total
 -----------------------------------------------------------
  jan                 100                   1000
  feb                 200                   2000
  march               700                   8000
  april               1000                  13000
```

I have tried many ways but couldnt make it.Can you please take a look on this? I really need help. Thanks!

Comment: GROUP BY the UNION result!

Comment: as @jarlh suggested, do a group by on month name from your output

Comment: can you show me how? @BibinMatthew

Comment: @nurwahidah: SELECT monthname, sum(new_card_qty), sum(new card_total) from your_output GROUP BY monthname;

Comment: okay thanks! but how can i get the month is ascending order like january.. february.. march @BibinMatthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be achieved by Subquery and group by as below:

```
SELECT MonthName, SUM(new_card_qty), SUM(new_card_value)
FROM 
(SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp) as MonthName, COUNT(*) as new_card_qty, ISNULL(sum(cl.nc_deposit),0) as new_card_total
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl  ........
union all

SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, cl.nc_timestamp) as MonthName, COUNT(*) as new_card_qty, ISNULL(sum(cl.nc_deposit),0) as new_card_total 
FROM dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs cl ......) AS A
GROUP BY MonthName
```

Comment: i do what you have suggested but im getting this error if i dont put the group by in the first query      @Mittal                                                           Column 'dbfastshosted.dbo.fh_mf_new_card_logs.nc_timestamp' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: i managed to avoid the error as i also put the group by in both subquery @mittal.. anyway thanks for your help!